# really compress a PDF file

Tags: pdf, compression

I'm trying all the online solutions that promise to compress a pdf file.
It is a scan of 13 pages with a file size of 3.52 MB. Nothing works!

I also tried Adobe Acrobat DC, but this pdf file doesn't seem to apply any compression. I would at least know the reason.

Comment: 13 pages of text and 13 pages of images are very different things.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the PDF document?

Comment: Try Adobe Acrobat DC's reduced size mode. If there's no changed there's not a lot that can be done because as mentioned, it's already compressed

Comment: @seth Yes, you understood the question perfectly

Comment: @edi No, it's not possible.  This is personal data

Comment: @sathyajith-bhat It's the first thing I did.  No gain in terms of size

Comment: @nicovon if I understood it ... why didn't you add the detail? Is it 13 pages of text or 13 pages of images (BMP, 8k resolution or gifs at 32x32?)? 13 pages of images at ~4MB is probably already pretty good. 13 pages of pure text might be a bit big.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to give a definite answer with the details given in the question, but:

PDF files are usually already compressed. In particular images that are part of the PDF files are nearly always already compressed.

You can't compress something that is already compressed again (or infinite compression would be possible, just run the compression program multiple times, until it gets small enough).

So if you want to reduce the size of your PDF file, you must extract the images, change them in some way (for example, convert them to a lower resolution), and then replace them in the PDF file.

While this is doable, I don't know any standard tools for doing that.

So it's probably simpler to just re-create your PDF file, using different, smaller images in the first place.

Comment: I exported the pdf as png, then with Photoshop I acted on the resolution using File> Script> Image Processor. In this way I managed to remove about 1.41 MB from the initial size of 3.52 MB. Only that in this way also the size of the pages that make up the pdf has decreased and I don't like this much. Are there other smarter compression types?

Comment: Exporting the *whole* PDF as PNG isn't a particular good way to do that, because, as you noticed, the overall quality gets worse. There are no "smarter compression types", but as I wrote, you can try to modify *only the images* (which probably make up most of the size). Any attempt by you to just use the complete PDF file and apply a random tool without understanding how to extract images will probably not work.

Comment: The *best* way is to scan your 13 pages again, using different scanning settings to get smaller images with acceptably quality.

Comment: Yes I know that the simplest solution would be to re-scan the pages with a dpi with a good quality / size ratio. And in fact I hoped there was an emulator that reproduces what the scanner is capable of doing. My pdf file is the product of a scan, so I believe that the whole page is considered an image, so I cannot modify a single image. The test I did before consisted in exporting all the pages, each in a PNG file, then after resizing them, combine them again in a pdf. But the result didn't excite me, the quality is acceptable, it's the size in the pdf viewer that I don't like.

Comment: You could extract page creating an individual image file, manipulate the image allowing you to compress the image, then replace the current image.  This does not guarantee the image will be any smaller though.

Comment: @ramhound That's exactly what I did, but I had to resize the images to get a lighter file.  I don't like the result

Answer (score 0):

File size of 3.52MB is very small for a 13 page PDF document.  It may not be possible to compress any further.  However, if the PDF consists of mostly images (assuming that it was "scanned" as images as indicated by the author above), there are few things you can try.

Since you already have Adobe Acrobat DC (not the free Adobe Acrobat Reader), try exporting the given PDF file as a PDF file using "print".  I don't know why, but in some cases, exporting it this way reduced the file size up to 90% when I had a PDF with images.

Open the original PDF file.  From the menu, select "File" -> "Print" (or Ctrl-P).  Select "Adobe PDF" as the printer.  This option is available only if Adobe Acrobat DC is installed.  Check the print settings to make sure it will print every page.  Then press "Print" button.  It will prompt you to save it as a new PDF file.

[image: Step 1]

Once, I was able to shrink a 5MB PDF file down to 350k, but this is highly dependent on the type of image and its original size.  If it was already highly compressed, I doubt that it will see any improvement.

Also you can try "Reduce File Size" option within the Adobe Acrobat DC.  Go to "File" -> "Save As...", and then check the "Reduce File Size".  Another way is to go to "Tool" -> "Optimize PDF" -> "Reduce File Size" (button on top) and then save.   I saw small reduction in file size, around 30%.

Another option is to use [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) software. Open the PDF, select "Export to PDF", and in the option, reduce the DPI to 150 and quality to 50%, and then save.

Final option is to use command line based software like [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) or [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php), which can resize the embedded images in the PDF. However, it is hard to use for the average users.